# i want my code to not work while i click on w,a,s,d keys

Tags: python, tkinter

i need my python code which will work unless i click "W,A,S,D" Keys

i dont know how to use case thing

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, width=400,  height=400)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="last key pressed:  ", width=20)
        self.label.pack(fill="both", padx=100, pady=100)

        self.label.bind
        self.label.bind
        self.label.bind
        self.label.bind

        # give keyboard focus to the label by default, and whenever
        # the user clicks on it
        self.label.focus_set()
        self.label.bind("<1>", lambda event: self.label.focus_set())
```

Comment: Whats wrong right now?

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? What is already happening, and how should it stop?

Comment: nothing is wrong with my code assume that there is a code that running properly but i want to add a structure that make my code not work till i stop pressing "w" or "a" or "s" or "d" keys

Comment: Can you please  rephrase your question for better understanding ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

```
import Tkinter as tk
stops = ["W","S","D","A"]
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,stops):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, width=400,  height=400)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="last key pressed:  ", width=20)
        self.label.pack(fill="both", padx=100, pady=100)
 
    #   something like that you need
        for stop in stops:
            if stop == (self.label,parent):
                return
            

        self.label.bind
        self.label.bind
        self.label.bind
        self.label.bind

        # give keyboard focus to the label by default, and whenever
        # the user clicks on it
        self.label.focus_set()
        self.label.bind("<1>", lambda event: self.label.focus_set())
```

Comment: Using `return` in an `__init__()` method will end the method's execution immediately, it won't wait. Also, the `return` statement will never actually be run here: when using `for stop in stops:`, `stop` will be a string; either `"W"`, `"S"`, `"D"`, or `"A"`. Hence, `if stop == (self.label, parent)` will never be `True`. Another thing: you only check for key presses when the class is initialized, so this code will only check for key presses once: on startup. So basically, this code is no better than the OP's.